# Chamando função de um Controller X através de um Controller Y (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!

Bom, estou com a seguinte questão me batendo à cabeça. Hoje eu possuo uma rotina no CRON que roda uma determinada função de um Controller X da minha aplicação.

Entretanto, eu gostaria que ao usuário realizar determinada ação (que é processada em outro Controller, vamos chamar de Y), ele execute essa rotina manualmente.

**Existe uma maneira de executar uma função de um Controller a partir de outro Controller com o CI?** E caso existe, por acaso isso fere ao MVC em que o mesmo é trabalhado? Ou existe uma forma melhor de tratar essa situação?

Realmente por questão de organização do código precisaria que as duas funções ficassem em Controllers separados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos às dúvidas.

> Existe uma maneira de executar uma função de um Controller a partir de outro Controller com o CI? E caso existe, por acaso isso fere ao MVC em que o mesmo é trabalhado? Ou existe uma forma melhor de tratar essa situação?

Existe. Acredito que para esse problema existam várias soluções e que dependendo do caso, umas se tornam mais viáveis que as outras. Entretanto, vou citar aqui apenas as soluções que conheço e que não ferem o padrão MVC.

## Herança

Uma das maneiras de solucionar o problema é através de Herança.

Para tal é necessário criar um *[Controller Core](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)* que será herdado pelos demais *Controllers* da sua aplicação (X e Y no caso) e dentro dele você pode implementar a lógica que o *CRON* está executando.

Por exemplo:

./application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected function _rotina()
    {
        // Lógica
    }
}
```

./application/controllers/Controller_x.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_x extends MY_Controller {

    // Action executada pelo CRON
    public function action()
    {
        // Executa a rotina...
        $this->_rotina();
    }
}
```

./application/controllers/Controller_y.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controller_y extends MY_Controller {

    // Action executada pelo outro Controller
    public function action()
    {
        // Executa a rotina...
        $this->_rotina();
    }
}
```

## Helpers

Outra forma de resolver o problema no *CodeIgniter* é utilizando *[Helpers](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)*.

Para isso, deve ser criado um *Helper* customizado na sua aplicação.

Por exemplo:

./application/helpers/rotina_helper.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('rotina'))
{
    function rotina()
    {
        // Lógica
    }
}
```

E dentro das *actions* dos seus *Controllers* X e Y basta carregar o *Helper* e utilizar:

```
$this->load->helper('rotina');

// Executa a rotina
rotina();
```

Comment: Show! Eu até tinha pensando na questão dos helpers, mas como é uma rotina um tanto quanto complexa não me parecia que cabia bem como um "helper", acredito que essa ideia do Controller Core vai me atender, valeu!

Comment: Realmente, os *Helpers* ajudam até certo ponto. Aqui utilizo bastante a questão da Herança por ser bem mais escalável.